# "If people were not there for their friends when they {need/needed} them" - which tense is correct?

Tags: conditional-constructions

I was writing this sentence:

> If people were not there for their friends when they **need** them the most, the world wouldn't be a nice place to live.

I know that according to the rule of second conditional the first part should be in simple past and in the second we should use *would*. However, saying *needed* in my sentence would make it sound to me as if I was talking about a past event when in fact I am talking about a hypothetical situation.

What is the correct tense that I should use in this sentence?

Comment: Technically speaking, *...when they **needed** them most*. Your Present Tense version would work better if you'd started with *If people **are** not there for their friends...* (in which case it would end with *...the world **won't / will not** be a nice place to live*). Both versions are fine, so long as you're consistewnt with the tenses. Note that the ***were*** version isn't actually ***Past** Tense* - it's ***subjunctive / unreal*** (people ***are*** in fact nice, so not being nice is an unreal hypothetical situation).

Comment: (I think this is one of those contexts where thinking about "numbered conditionals" isn't particularly helpful. But I think that about *every* context! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Got it! Thank you so much for your very helpful comment!

Comment: Most native speakers who are not linguists don't even know what 'numbered conditionals are'. I have to look them up.